# JavaScript math issue

Tags: javascript, python

I see this in JavaScript

```
2-(1/3 * 1) // => Returns 1.66666666667
```

but,

```
4-(1/3 * 7) // => Returns 1.6666666667
```

This is one less `6` than the previous result. This is awkard, because both expressions are suposed equal to `5/3`

I tried to do the same thing using Python, and both expressions returned the same result.

Comment: It's just whatever arbitrary precision your IDE decides to report to. If you care to report to a specific precision, then specify it manually.

Comment: Yes. What is your question? If you are relying on a specific number of sixes in the result then you are on very shaky ground.

Comment: Please does someone know the usual *floating point precision* resource to link to?

Comment: +Borodin The problem is that those expressions should return the same value, and they're not. How can I get this to work?

Comment: No, they both *"should"* return an infinitely-recurring decimal number. Since that is impossible the language does its best, and since *"best"* isn't definitive you will see different versions of it, even within the same language.

Comment: It's definately no news that Python is more reliable for mathematical purposes than javascript

Comment: Why do you think those expressions should give the same value? Do it on a piece of paper and see what you get. (Incidentally, you'll get a slightly different result than the computer gives you, because the computer isn't using decimal.)

Comment: Also useful: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Here's a new one: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the intermediates are an order of magnitude different:

```
0.3333333333333333 * 1
#>>> 0.3333333333333333

0.3333333333333333 * 7
#>>> 2.333333333333333
```

This means that the first will be rounded to an 8x greater granularity than the second. Because of Python's `repr` being pretty and rounding to the nearest decimal that evaluates exactly to the floating point, this shows up as a 10x difference in granularity.

To compare visually:

```
0.3333333333333333
2.333333333333333
```

See how they have the same number of significant figures but a different number of decimal places.

When you do `number - multiplication`, you end up "unshifting" this value, so its ends up with more error than before in relative terms, although the exact (absolute) error is the same.